# I need to send an alert back to the user when there is no records found

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

This is my post request from nodejs server

```
app.post('/api/users', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {
    if (!req.body) return res.sendStatus(400);
    console.log(req.body);
    var data = req.body;
    db.collection('users').findOne({
        username: data.username
    }, (err, result) => {
        if (result === null) {
            db.collection('users').insertOne(data, function (err) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log("Record inserted!");
                res.status(200).send("recordInserted");
            })
        } else {
            console.log("Already exists");

            res.status(500).send("userExists");
        }
    })

})
```

This is my ajax request

```
$('#signupForm').on('submit', function () {
    var userData = {
        fullName: $("#fullName").val(),
        username: $("#username").val(),
        password: $("#password").val(),
        email: $("#email").val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        data: userData,
        dataType: "text",
        url: "/api/users",  
        function (data, status) { 
            if(data== 'recordInserted'){
                alert("Recors inserted");
                console.log("Inserted \n" + data +"\n" + status);
            }
            else if(data == 'userExists') {
                alert("User exists");
                console.log(data + "\n " + status);

            }
         }
    });


});
```

I cant send back the response to the ajax request and because of that the page doesn't reload or show an error if the user already exists

Comment: status code 500 is an error to ajax

Comment: you need to catch that error in error callback as this is a failure response `500` statusCode

Answer (score 0):

As a first order of business, the preferred way for awhile now to handle responses in AJAX has been to utilize deferred objects.

```js
let request = $.ajax({url: 'google.com', type:'get'});

request.done(function(response){
 // handle response
});
```

Beyond that, your back-end looks to be fine.

**Although!**

I would highly recommend changing how you go about error handling on the server-side. If the server throws an error, the client will be left hanging until they timeout. Its best to alert the client that an error has occurred, as well.

Answer (score 0):

use of e.preventDefault(); method will stop the page from being reload. you can copy paste the code

```
    $('#signupForm').on('submit', funfunction(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let userData = {
            fullName: $("#fullName").val(),
            username: $("#username").val(),
            password: $("#password").val(),
            email: $("#email").val()
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            data: userData,
            dataType: "text",
            url: "/api/users",  
            function (data, status) { 
                if(data== 'recordInserted'){
                    alert("Recors inserted");
                    console.log("Inserted \n" + data +"\n" + status);
                }
                else if(data == 'userExists') {
                    alert("User exists");
                    console.log(data + "\n " + status);

                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: and strictly use **let** instead of **var**